# Validation for Email, Web address and phone number, but bit tricky

Tags: android, validation

- I have three fields in my form

1] Email address

2] Phone number

3] Web address

- **I know how to give validation for all, but i have diff requirement**
- What i want is if all fields are null no validation is applicable(no need to check)
- if 1 field is empty and rest are filed check for those filed only not empty filed
- I don't know what to do with this thing,
- need to check for null/empty if null no need to to check for validation if field is not null/empty then check for that field only not other field

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
if (!emailAddressEditText.getText().toString().matches(""){
    //Apply your validation
}
if (!phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString().matches("")){
   //Apply your validation
}
if (!webAddressEditText.getText().toString().matches("")){
   //Apply your validation
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: `TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())` would also work

Comment: how do i call method if any single validation is true ?? i think this may start method more than 1 time , if all conditions are true

Comment: @Risk you can add validation for each edit text or add flags for each one